# Return an Input in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking to return an input element that takes socket username in componentWillMount which will be used in render function, but I dont know how I should be doing this. Is there a way I could do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do - are you trying to get input and assign it to a variable before `render` ever runs?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to collect an information before the render function..

Comment: I doubt that is possible, and it's **definitely** against the React philosophy. Perhaps it would be wiser to have a container component with an input and a button which passes the username as a prop once the button is pressed (you could use a ternary so the component is only created once the button is pressed)